# Parsing a Shell Command with Environment Variables in Haskell

Tags: shell, haskell

Haskell's `System.Process` provides us with a way to convert a `String` into a shell command via `shell`:

```hs
System.Process.createProcess (System.Process.shell $ "a_command with some arguments")
```

The problem is that `shell` doesn't parse environment variables.  Is there a library command which converts a shell string into a shell call, that is sensitive to environment variables?  Something like

```hs
System.Process.createProcess (shellWithEnv "ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=value a_command with some arguments")
```

?

**EDIT:** More evidence `shell` does not pick this up:

```
GHCI> shell "ENV=value echo hi"
CreateProcess {cmdspec = ShellCommand "ENV=value echo hi", cwd = Nothing, env = Nothing, std_in = Inherit, std_out = Inherit, std_err = Inherit, close_fds = False, create_group = False, delegate_ctlc = False, detach_console = False, create_new_console = False, new_session = False, child_group = Nothing, child_user = Nothing, use_process_jobs = False}
```

Here `env = Nothing`.

Comment: Could not reproduce. `createProcess (shell "A=B env | grep ^A=")` prints `A=B`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? As @DanielWagner has illustrated, the VAR=VALUE syntax at the start of a command will cause the shell to set up that environment variable with that value before running the command. This is good enough for many things, where it's the command itself that needs the env var to be set. Or is it important that the variable gets set before the _shell_ is started (eg does its value affect the shell's startup scripts)? In that case you'll need something like Willem Van Den Onsen's answer.

Comment: Why is `env = Nothing` a problem?

Comment: It turns out (to my surprise, not to everyone else's) that you all were right: `shell` imports environment variables (despite not updating `env`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`shell :: String -> CreateProcess`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.11.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:shell) is just a function that constructs a `CreateProcess` object. You can update the `env` attribute [**`CreateProcess`** data](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.11.0/docs/System-Process.html#t:CreateProcess) of the record with:

```
import System.Process(CreateProcess(env), createProcess, shell)

createProcess ((\x -> x {env=Just [("ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE", "value")]}) (shell "a_command with some arguments"))
```

Comment: `env` isn't necessary; environment variables can be imported from the string as described in the post.